# update a cell in tableview also update another cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I am little bit confused in a scenario, I think its my logical mistake please help me to resolve it, i am really confused.
**Scenario is that**:

1. There is Questions in Form.
2. Every Question Have There Answer, 1st is **YES**, 2nd is **NO**, And 3rd is **Not Applicable**.
3. By Default **YES** is selected.
4. If User Click on **Yes** And **Not Applicable** there is not change in **UI** occurs, But if User Click on **NO** there is a **textfield** shows In which user should describe Reason of **NO**.

Now these all thing Happens But a problem is occur when user clicks on NO the textfield shows but when user scroll down another cell shows textfield, and NO is also selected on that cell, which is not selected by user. I think its issue with index or my logic please help, i am using delegate pattern for button events.

please see the attachments below

[When User Select NO in Question No. 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghrPE.png)

[And Scroll Down than Question No. 6 is also shown as NO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8qZ6.png)

Hope Any One Help me, Thanks in advance

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FormCell", for: indexPath) as! FormCell

    cell.questionLbl.text = "Question No \(indexPath.row): What is Your Name"
    cell.index = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

func yesBtnPressedAt(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("YES")

    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! FormCell
    if(cell.tag == indexPath.row){
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        cell.yesBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.selectedAnswerColor
        cell.noBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.unSelectedAnswerColor
        cell.notApplicableBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.unSelectedAnswerColor

        cell.resonTextFiled.isHidden = true
        cell.goToTeamBtn.isHidden = true
        cell.heightForMaineView.constant = 89.0
        cell.heightForTextField.constant = 0.0

        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

func noBtnPressedAt(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("NO")

    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! FormCell

    if(cell.tag == indexPath.row){

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        cell.yesBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.unSelectedAnswerColor
        cell.noBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.selectedAnswerColor
        cell.notApplicableBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.unSelectedAnswerColor

        cell.resonTextFiled.isHidden = false
        cell.goToTeamBtn.isHidden = false

        cell.heightForMaineView.constant = 129.0
        cell.heightForTextField.constant = 30.0

        self.tableView.endUpdates()

    }
}

func notApplicableBtnPressedAt(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Not Applicable")

    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! FormCell

    if(cell.tag == indexPath.row){

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        cell.yesBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.unSelectedAnswerColor
        cell.noBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.unSelectedAnswerColor
        cell.notApplicableBtn.backgroundColor = ColorUtilities.selectedAnswerColor

        cell.resonTextFiled.isHidden = true
        cell.goToTeamBtn.isHidden = true

        cell.heightForMaineView.constant = 89.0
        cell.heightForTextField.constant = 0.0

        self.tableView.endUpdates()

    } }
```

Comment: Please include code! I might be able to help!

Comment: you can share your code?

Comment: is override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell   getting called when you update your tableview by any chance? @MuhammadAhmedBaig. Try printing something in there

Comment: i think there is an indexing aur logical error as i update cell number 0 and scroll down it automatically update another cell example cell number 5, @toiavalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@["your indexPath"] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

nice work

Answer (score 0):

it's all about reusable cells mechanics in tableview, for more information need some code contained in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FormCell", for: indexPath) as! FormCell

        cell.questionLbl.text = "Question No \(indexPath.row): What is Your Name"
        cell.index = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        
        return cell
    }

Comment: you need to configure state (show textField or not) of your cell, as i said before in tableview all cell is reuse, and you just reload cell from first question (when first question cell is become unload). I think you can make object like `questionObject` and property: `questionObject.isAnsweredYes` then just make state - `cell.textfield.hidden = questionObject.isAnsweredYes`

Comment: no this not occurs i think you can't understand my problem, the cell on which user change state is not do any problem the problem is that another cell is also change its state

Answer (score 0):

If Jupiters answer is what you looking for... Here is a Swift version

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates();
self.tableView reloadRows(atIndexPath: "your indexPath", withRowAnimation: .none);
self.tableView.endUpdates();
```